# How to have differents screens with custom sizes? (Kivi)

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I want to have several `Screen`, each one with a different size but I can't. Each time I try to change the size of **one** screen, Kivy change the size of all.
What can I do?
I have been trying using `kivy.core.window.Window` and `Window.size = (x,y)`, but it change the size of all the screens, even if I wrote that line inside the `__init__` function of each screen, because when they are loaded to the `ScreenManager`, the `__init__` is also loaded.

#### This is an `.py` example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Main(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.size = (900, 500)     

class Login(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Login, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        Window.size = (400, 300)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Screen_Manager()

MyApp().run()
```

#### This is an '.kv' example:

```
<Screen_Manager>:
    id: screen_manager
    Main:
    Login:

<Login>:
    name: 'login'
    Button:
        text: 'Go to Main'
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'main'

<Main>:
    name: 'main'
    Button:
        text: 'Go to Login'
        on_press: root.manager.current = 'login'
```

#### My only idea of how to fix this is do:

#### `.kv`

```
#:import Window kivy.core.window.Window
<Screen_Manager>:
     [...]
<Login>:
     [...]
     Button:
         [...]
         on_press:
              Window.size = (900, 400)
              root.manager.current = 'main'
<Main>:
     [...]
     Button:
         [...]
         on_press:
              Window.size = (400, 300)
              root.manager.current = 'login'
```

But... I don't like it much...

Comment: I was under the impression kivy was based on a single main screen.   Are you looking to resize the window frame based on the displayed screen?

Comment: @RufusVS, exactly, is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely don't want a screen to have to know the size of the screen it is transferring to.  I did a little research, and you just have to add a function (on_enter or on_pre_enter) in each screen.  Use this for your .py program:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen, ScreenManager
from kivy.core.window import Window

class Screen_Manager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Main(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Main, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Window.size = (900, 500)     

class Login(Screen):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(Login, self).__init__(**kwargs)

    def on_pre_enter(self):
        Window.size = (400, 300)


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return Screen_Manager()

MyApp().run()
```

You could probably be even cooler and create a subclass of Screen which contained the default size and the on_pre_enter method, if you plan on doing many screens of different sizes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Also, you have already answered my question so you don't have to answer this another one, but, Do you know how to center the App after change the size of the screen? When I change the size is increase or reduce only from the right and bottom side of the program, not the four sides, so the window get "uncentered" after change it size. If you are interested --> [you can answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46354469/7655838)